# Align image in center if wither then container

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I added picture that is wider than viewport I lookat ,, somewhere 1000px wide ,, and I'd like it to be aligned in the middle somehow ..

The smaller picture of eye lower would need to be as is ..

I played with `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` and align attributes and `margin: -50%` but I guess I'd need to use media queries for that ..

This is my blog:

http://blog.mk-dizajn.com/

thanks for any help ..

Comment: it needs to be as this http://i.imgur.com/rE529nb.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this rules to your images and it will scale to your viewport

**CSS**

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

But you should be sure that you dont have width and height attributes on your image tag

Comment: it got shrinked to container width now, same as @alex and all you guys, it needs to be as this: http://imgur.com/rE529nb

Answer (score 0):

Add width = "100%" to the img tag.

```
<img src="http://blog.mk-dizajn.com/media/left_right_side_of_brain-1280x768.jpg" width="100%" alt="Are you right, or left :)">
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/9nMzK/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="image_container">
     <img src="picture.png">
</div>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
#image_container {
   position: absolute;  /* Alternative get this relative to the parent */
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding-left: 50%;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}
#image_container:after {
   clear: both;
}
#image_container > img {
   margin-left: -50%;
}
```

Explanation: You give the parent container a padding left of 50%. To get the image dynamically centered give the image a margin-left of -50%; This way you get it centered.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Give width to your image tag as 100%.Replace this code it will work

```
img {
display: block;
margin: 0 0 1rem;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add you code css

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

this technique will give your image resize when you change the screen size